# How Would I fix receiving and invalid token error? (repl.it)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm somewhat new to node.js as a friend recommended it to me today, so this is technically my first time using it. I've decided to use repl.it to host this as I lack the resources to do so locally but I've been encountering an error.

My script right now is meant to have my user account leave every server while leaving whitelisted ID's untouched. This is what it looks like.

```
global.print = console.log

var {Client, IntentsBitField} = require("discord.js")
var bits = Object.values(IntentsBitField.Flags).filter(val => { return Number.isInteger(val)})
const client = new Client({ intents: bits })
const whitelist = [ // Array of guild IDs to NOT leave

 'id1'
 'id2'
 'id3'

]

async function main() {
var proms = []
var guild_collection = await client.guilds.fetch({limit: 200})
guild_collection = guild_collection.filter(guild => (!whitelist.includes(guild.id))).toJSON()

guild_collection.forEach(guild => { proms.push(guild.leave()) })

await Promise.all(proms) // Waits for all of them to be done tho...
print("Left every server..")
}

client.login(process.env['token']).then(() => {
  print("Moving forwards...")
  main()
})
```

It's set to use the repl's "secrets" feature, which is where I've put my desired token, but I receive a "TokenInvalid" error.

```
/home/runner/Leave-Servers/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:136
    const invalidToken = new DiscordjsError(ErrorCodes.TokenInvalid);
                         ^

Error [TokenInvalid]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (/home/runner/Leave-Servers/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:136:26)
    at Client.login (/home/runner/Leave-Servers/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:226:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Leave-Servers/index.js:21:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) {
  code: 'TokenInvalid'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Am I perhaps doing something wrong?

I have tried just using the regular token in the form of

```
client.login("YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN");
```

But this also resulted in the same error, and also puts my token at a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with the OP, it seems like they're trying to use a script outside of the OAuth2/bot API.

See: [Automated user accounts (self-bots)](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

Such a thing is actually forbidden, and not possible through [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org) because the library was made for Discord bots.

##### Original answer

As per [Secrets and Environment Variables](https://docs.replit.com/programming-ide/workspace-features/secrets#javascript),

> ##### JavaScript
>
> ```js
> console.log(process.env.MY_SECRET);
> ```

Where `MY_SECRET` is the secret's key.

Comment: Wouldn't line 21 cover that already?

process.env['token']

Shouldn't that be valid?

Comment: @PeytonS. Yeah, after a bit of research, I think *both* are the same, but still it's worth trying the one I mentioned. Also, are you sure that your token is valid? Try to create a new one, worth try.

Comment: Tried making a new token under the name "token_real" and I have received the same 'TokenInvalid' error.

Comment: @PeytonS. What do you mean by "under the name `token_real`"? Revoke and create a new token from Discord Dashboard, then paste the new token in the same place of the old token (i.e replace) in Replit secrets.

Comment: I meant in the term of using the repl secrets, my apologies, I misunderstood. The token that I'm using is valid however, this is meant to be a script to ran for the user and not a bot.

Comment: OK; well, you can't do that. The library you're using is actually made for Discord bots, not [Automated user accounts (self-bots)](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-). And those aren't really allowed.

Comment: Ah I see, my apologies then, and thanks for answering!